# I'm receiving a null when I'm deleting a product?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

so I created a Cart redux wherein it will store all products and the total cost of it.

This is my shopping cart, and I can already sum up all the orders

[image]

And this is what happened when I delete 1 of it, example i delete the **Medtech7**

This is what my redux extension shows
[image]
[image]

This is how I pass my data from cart to redux

```
const handleClick =(id) =>{
    dispatch(deleteProduct(id))
}
```

I'm guessing that my deleteProduct is the problem. is my formula wrong?

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cart",
    initialState: {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0
    },
    reducers: {
        resetState: (state) => {
            state.products = [];
            state.quantity = 0;
            state.total = 0
        },
        addProduct: (state,action) =>{
            state.quantity += 1;
            state.products.push(action.payload);
            state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity
        },
        deleteProduct: (state,action) =>{
            state.products.splice(state.products.findIndex((arrow) => arrow._id === action.payload),1)
            state.quantity -= 1;
            state.total -= action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity

        }
    }
})

export const {addProduct, deleteProduct} = cartSlice.actions
export default cartSlice.reducer
```

Comment: what are the values of `totals`, `action.payload.price` and `action.payload.quantity` when you perform the deletion?

Comment: total = NaN,

`action.payload.price` = `undefined`,

`action.payload.quantity` = `undefined`,

Comment: you wrote you can dispatch correctly `addProduct` (which I guess real values are passed), if `deleteProduct` dispatch does not work it means you are not passing real values

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good approach, but it works, if there's any other approach, feel free to give it, hehe.

I throw **product._id** which is **id** in handleclick. And grab the **product.price** which is **price**. Since price is a string, I convert it to a number, and multiply It to the current quantity.

```
const handleClick =(id,price) =>{
    const itemPrice = Number(price)
    dispatch(deleteProduct({id,quantity: cart.quantity, price: itemPrice}))
}
```

cartSlice.js

```
deleteProduct: (state,action) =>{
    state.quantity -= 1;
    state.products.splice(state.products.findIndex((arrow) => arrow._id 
     === action.payload),1)
    console.log((action.payload.quantity-1), action.payload.price)
    state.total = (action.payload.quantity-1) * action.payload.price
}
```